# Is there a way to add a GL Transaction and Normal Transaction in Quickbook?

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

I want to add GL accounts and normal account transaction in quickbook. So I can see separate report for both. Is it possible to add GL Transaction and Normal Transaction in Quickbook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QuickBooks does not have any concept of a "GL Transaction" or a "Normal Transaction".

It does have Invoices, Payments, Sales Orders, Journal Entries, and other specific types of transactions.

You're going to have to be a bit more specific about what you're looking for...